# On a property of Fourier coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need to prove the following:

If $(\Phi_n)_{n\ge0}$ is an orthonormal system of integrable functions defined on some interval $[a,b]$, and $(c_n)_n$ is a sequence of reals such that $\sum c_n \Phi_n$ converges uniformly to an integrable function $f$ on $[a,b]$, then:

$$c_m = \int_a^b f(x) \Phi_m(x) dx, \ \ \forall \ m \in \mathbb N$$

If it can be guaranteed that for a given $m \in \mathbb N$, $\sum_{n} c_n \Phi_n \Phi_m$ converges uniformly as well, then we can do:

$$\int_a^b f(x) \Phi_m(x) dx = \int_a^b \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n \Phi_n(x) \right) \Phi_m(x) dx = \int_a^b \sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} c_n \Phi_n(x) \Phi_m(x) dx = \sum_{n=0, n \neq m}^{\infty} c_n \int_a^b \Phi_n(x) \Phi_m(x) dx + c_m \int_a^b (\Phi_m(x))^2 dx = 0 + c_m \times 1 = c_m$$

The question is: why need the series $\sum_{n} c_n \Phi_n \Phi_m$ converge uniformly as well for a given $m \in \mathbb N$? For this to be achieved, $\Phi_m$ should be bounded, that's, $\exists$ $M>0$, such that $||\Phi_m||_{\infty} \le M$. Why need this occur?

Thanks.

Comment: By integrable, do you mean Riemann integrable?

Comment: @zhw. Yes. $\\\\\$

Comment: If $\Phi_m$ is Riemann integrable, it is by definition bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us start with a general claim:

Let $(g_n),\quad n=1,2,\ldots$, be a sequence of functions which converges uniformly to the function $g$. Let $h$ be a square-integrable function. Then the sequence $(g_nh)$ converges by integral to $gh$.

To prove the claim, we may assume $g=0$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have $$\left(\int g_nhdx\right)^2\leq\int g_n^2dx\cdot\int h^2dx,$$and the claim follows since uniform convergence yields square integral convergence.

We return to the posted question. If we may assume that $\Phi_m$ is square integrable, we deduce from the above claim that the sum in question converges by integral to the desired function. This is actually enough, as we all agree.

Comment: Thank you. I agree. But I'm asking about another thing.

Comment: @BolzWeir Then I don't understand what you are asking. If it's important for you, maybe you should edit your post and explain what it is exactly that you're after.

Comment: I was after why does the series $\sum_n c_n \Phi_n \Phi_m$ converges uniformly as well. You have clarified that uniform convergence is not necessary, what is necessary is convergence by integral. But still, why does convergence by integral occur? Thank you.

Comment: @BolzWeir I see. Please have a look at the answer now.